# Orchard CMS: How to display different views for summary and detail display type of Tags_ShowTags shape?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I need to display different views for summary and detail display type for TagsPart, but it contains only one shape Tags_ShowTags for both views.

```
protected override DriverResult Display(TagsPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
    return ContentShape("Parts_Tags_ShowTags",
        () => shapeHelper.Parts_Tags_ShowTags(Tags: part.CurrentTags.Select(x => new ShowTagViewModel { TagName = x })));
}
```

Is there way to create different views for shape Tags_ShowTags? Like this:
Tags.ShowTags-MyContentType.Detail.cshtml
Tags.ShowTags-MyContentType.Summary.cshtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marco Serralheiro's tip to use Atlernates allows to use different views for summary and detail display type without creating extra shapes. See following example:

```
<Match ContentType="MyContentType">
  <Match DisplayType="Summary">
    <Place Parts_Tags_ShowTags="Content:4;Alternate=Parts_Tags_ShowTag_MyContentType_Summary"/>
  </Match>
  <Match DisplayType="Detail">
    <Place Parts_Tags_ShowTags="Content:4;Alternate=Parts_Tags_ShowTag_MyContentType_Detail"/>
  </Match>
</Match>
```

View names:

```
/Views/Parts.Tags.ShowTag.MyContentType.Summary.cshtm
/Views/Parts.Tags.ShowTag.MyContentType.Detail.cshtml
```

Comment: This should be the preferred answer.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy, why doesn't this approach work for fields? I'm looking for a way to apply alternate fields templates in summary and detail modes.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't? There's nothing special about shapes that come from parts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Have you tried the Shape Tracing tool, to find what are the available alternates for that shape (http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools)? You can also take a look at http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates - Parts_Tags_ShowTags is used as example to explain alternates.

Edit:

I managed to increase the number of available alternates (that are available without the need to explicitly designate them in the placement.info file) following this tip: http://kobowi.co.uk/blog/2012/11/content-display-type-alternates-for-content-parts-in-orchard

In my own module I placed this "PartContentTypeAlternateFactory.cs":

```
using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation;
using System;

namespace MyModule.Name {
    public class PartContentTypeAlternateFactory : ShapeDisplayEvents {
        public override void Displaying(ShapeDisplayingContext context) {
            context.ShapeMetadata.OnDisplaying(displayedContext => {

                var shapeType = displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Type;
                var contentItem = displayedContext.Shape.ContentItem;

                if (contentItem == null) return;

                var displayType = displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.DisplayType;
                var contentType = contentItem.ContentType;

                // add a couple more alternates
                displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add(
                    String.Format("{0}__{1}", shapeType, displayType));
                displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add(
                    String.Format("{0}__{1}__{2}", shapeType, (string)contentType, displayType));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me a few more alternates to chose from, "out of the box". They even show up in the Shape Tracing tool, and one can use it to create the appropriate cshtml files.